# Maps API 3 Directions with fuzzy via co-ordinates

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I have a number of GPS co-ordinates that describe a route. My intention is to draw a polyline along the route, and then colour segments based on some data I have.

Problem is, the GPS coordinates can occur on the roadside either side of main roads. When using the obvious Directions service solution a lot of "back and forth" occurs as Google tries to get me either side of a split lane road[image: Poor pathing]
What I am aiming for is a direct route from A-H passing through every way point. I have considered reverse geocoding the coordinates to a street name and having the directions use the street as a way point, but that picks a specific point on the street that may not be related to the actual route. Single polylines are also not an option as some routes have turns in them.

Is there a way to 'fuzzy' my waypoints so that the directions are happy when passing within a certain radius of the points? If not, has anyone got any other solutions?

Thanks heaps.

Edit: It's also not an option to just not use the middle way points because sometimes the path is not optimal.

Also have tried my own fuzzy coords now, by +- some small value to each consecutive lat/lng pair. Unsurprisingly I ran into OVER_QUERY_LIMIT pretty soon.

Comment: Could you use a different transit mode, e.g. WALKING?

Comment: Actually did try WALKING, it was returning ZERO_RESULTS (presumably because there is no path along the motorway?).